# Steinberg UR824, set it to stereo mode in VLC

Tags: sound, video, pulseaudio, alsa, vlc

I have a Steinberg UR824 audio interface with two boxes plugged in. Since the interface has many inputs and outputs, VLC assumes it's a surround system even though it's only stereo.

When I play a video, I can only hear what's coming from the surround speakers from the front. Mostly music and some sound effects, but mostly no dialogs.

Is there a way to force VLC into stereo mode?

Comment: "Audio" / "Audio Device"?

Comment: Yes, but what do you mean exactly?

Comment: What devices are listed there?

Comment: In the system settings the HDMI / Displayport NVidia output, my onboard Realtek Built-in Audio, and Multichannel Output - Steinberg UR824. In the VLC Preferences, when I set the output module to ALSA, I can chose a ton of variations for each of these devices. None of the variations for my audio interface seem to work. Also found "Force stereo" somewhere, which didn't help neither. The sound output through my monitor with the Nvidia drivers works perfectly, though.

Comment: If no working stereo device is listed, then the hardware does not support playback with only two channels. You have to configure PulseAudio to treat it as a stereo device.

Comment: All the devices are listed and working. I can only chose multichannel output on my audio interface in the system settings. How would I change it to stereo in pulseaudio?

Comment: Good question! I'm sure there's some PulseAudio module ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution to this problem in this tutorial:

https://thedarkgod.wordpress.com/2013/08/26/having-pulseaudio-downmix-surround5-1-to-stereo/